# How to fix a minor JvYearGrid Control bug without reinstalling the entire JVCL Library

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, jedi

I just found a bug in JediVCL's JvYearGrid. The public set function below is not setting the supplied string value. I know how to fix the procedure but my question is how to change it without re-installing the entire JediVCL Library. Is there any workaround possible like accessing the properly functioning private member `SetCellData(string)`instead. I am on Delphi XE5 (came to know some private exposing techniques won't work on 10.2).

**What I tried**: I uninstalled the associated package `JvJansDesign` from the IDE, changed the code, cleaned, and reinstalled the package. But, it is not working i.e. it is referencing the **bugged** procedure from somewhere else and not the source file I am modifying (JEDI master\jvcl\run\JvYearGrid.pas). I confirmed it by putting showmessage() which were never triggered. **The modified procedure is never entered let alone the if else checks.**

**Note**: The procedure sets a string value to the selected cell in the year grid. Additionally, internally, a popup menu modifies this value successfully through `FYearData[Col, Row].InfoText := stringVar;` within the private member `SetCellData(string)`. I can modify from menu, but really need to do it programmatically.

```
function TJvYearGrid.GetSelDateText: string;
var
  DS: string;
begin
  if (Col < 1) or (Row < 1) then
    Exit;
  DS := FYearData[Col, Row].DisplayText;
  if DS = '' then
    Exit;
  Result := FYearData[Col, Row].InfoText;
end;

procedure TJvYearGrid.SetSelDateText(AText: string);
var
  DS, S: string;
begin

  if (Col < 1) or (Row < 1) then
    Exit;
  DS := FYearData[Col, Row].DisplayText;
  if DS = '' then
    Exit;
  FYearData[Col, Row].InfoText := s;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

*To repeat what I already did: uninstalled the package for JvJans Components (JvJansDesign190.bpl), Modified the only source file for JvYearGrid (inside run folder).*

The key was that, the `JvJansDesign190` package itself was not sufficient to modify the control because it depended on the build of another package `JvJans190`. If you open the **JVCL group project** for your Delphi product version (V19 for me), you can see these two. First you have to re-build the dependency (JvJans190), then clean and install the JvJansDesign190 on top of it.

This will refresh the design time component and there will be no discrepancy between the source file and the component behavior.

[image]